# Error al llamar a un metodo

Tags: java, poo

Estoy creando un programa con una `clase` llamada **Cuenta** con las características:

```
String Usuario;
double Cantidad;
```

Ya he creado los `get` y `set` para ellas, pero ahora tengo que implementar un `método` **Ingresar** que añada una cantidad a la cantidad, esto es lo que tengo de ese  `método` hasta ahora:

```
    public double ingresar(double ingreso) {

        int fondo;
        getCantidad();
        fondo = (int) (getCantidad() + ingreso);

        return fondo;
    }
```

En este **getCantidad** devuelve la cantidad que haya introducido el usuario, después intenta añadir el ingreso, que es una `variable` de tipo `double` que le pasamos como argumento. La llamada al `método` es esta:

```
        System.out.println("Indique la cantidad que desea ingresar");
        double ingreso = sc.nextDouble();
        ingresar(ingreso);
```

Me indica que ingresar es `non-static` y que no puede ser referenciado a uno `static`, creo.
¿Alguien podría explicarme qué tengo mal? Gracias

Comment: ¿El método ingresar(double ingreso) está en la clase Cuenta?

Comment: Sí, está dentro de la clase Cuenta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay errores conceptuales sobre POO

Los métodos pueden ser de instancia o de la clase (estáticos), por la forma en que declaras tu método es de instancia lo que implica que para usarlo debes crear un objeto primero y luego llamar el método a través del ese objeto.

```
Cuenta c = new Cuenta(argumentos);  // crear un objeto
c.ingresar( 1234.4);                // llama el método para esa cuenta
```

Acerca del método:

```
public double ingresar(double ingreso)
```

estas indicando que regresa un double pero fondo es un int, lo cual debes corregir.

Getters y Setters son métodos que se utilizan para manipular los campos de la clase cuando estos son private (generalmente), esto impide que otras clases accedan directamente a las campos, se utilizan igual que otros métodos.

El siguiente código es un ejemplo de como declarar la clase Cuenta

```
public class Cuenta {
  // campos privados
  private String usuario;  // los nombres de los campos empiezan en minúscula
  private double cantidad;
  // constructor
  public Cuenta(String usuario, double cantidad) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
  }
  // getters y setters
  public String getUsuario() { return usuario; }
  public void setUsuario(String usuario) { this.usuario = usuario; }
  public double getCantidad() { return cantidad;}
  public void setCantidad(double cantidad) {this.cantidad = cantidad;}
  //método de instancia 
  public double ingresar(double ingreso) {  
    // se puede acceder a los campos desde la misma clase sin usar get o set
    cantidad += ingreso;  
    System.out.println("ingresado "+ingreso+" total "+cantidad);
    return cantidad;  // retorna un double
  }
  // método estático recibe un objeto Cuenta
  public static double ingresarEstatico(Cuenta c, double cantidad) {
    c.cantidad += cantidad; 
    return c.getCantidad();
  }
}
```

Uso desde main (por ejemplo)

```
    // crear un objeto con constructor
    Cuenta c1 = new Cuenta("Nombre", 1294.43);    
    System.out.println("Saldo "+c1.getCantidad());
    // ingreso con método de instancia
    c1.ingresar(1238.89);
    System.out.println("Saldo "+c1.getCantidad());
    // ingreso con método estático
    Cuenta.ingresarEstatico(c1, 4500.43);
    System.out.println("Saldo "+c1.getCantidad());
```

Answer (score 0):

El error `non-static` quiere decir que no puede acceder a tu `método` `no estático` llamado **ingresar**, ya que este no es estático como el `método` desde el que lo estás mandando a llamar, que me imagino que es el `public static void main`, si te fijas, ahí indica la palabra reservada `static`, lo que quiere decir que esa `función` y todas las `funciones` que sean `static` pertenecen a la clase que los contiene, por lo tanto, si quieres llamar una `función no estática` desde otra que sí es `estática`, debes crear una `instancia` de la función `no estática` para poder acceder a ella.

De otra manera más fácil y rápida, es que hagas estática tu `función` **ingresar**, de tal manera que quede así:

```
public static double ingresar(){
 
 //Tu código
}
```

De esta manera ya no sería necesario crear la `instancia` y podrías llamar tu `función` directamente.